# Enumerate graphs with hexagonal faces

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many are there non isotopic (in a sphere) embeddings of planar, simple, connected graph embeddings, which vertices are of degree at least two with $n$ vertices, such that all faces are hexagons (including external face)? A given graph and its mirror is counted as one. The number for $n=12$ is $12$ as shown in the figure:

[image]

Comment: What's your stance on chirality? The graph you've drawn has an opposite embedding, which can only be reached by an orientation-reversing map. Is that one or two embeddings in the count?

Comment: Also, multigraphs. At 10 or more vertices, it's possible to set up a planar multigraph with more than one edge between the same pair of vertices. Is this allowed or not?

Comment: A given graph and its mirror image can be counted as one. No multigraphs, as I consider them to have bigonal faces.

Comment: Wel clearly the number is $0$ for all odd $n$ and $n=2,4$. For $n=0,6,8$ it is $1$ and for $n=10$ it is $4$. I very strongly doubt any sensible closed form exists, as it is not even easy to determine the number of isomorphism types for large $n$. For $n=12$ the number is at least $19$, and there are some graphs that do not embed in a sphere.

Comment: @old I see that I have misunderstood your question; I hadn't counted $g_2$ and $g_3$ because they contain $4$-cycles, but indeed each has a unique embedding (up to reflection) for which this is not a face.

Comment: Why did you remove the image?

Comment: As for multigraphs, what if each "bigonal face" is bisected by a path with 4 internal degree-2 vertices?

Comment: What do you mean by "isotopic"? What do you mean by "face" if the graph is not 2-connected?

Comment: I have edited my post adding more details

Comment: Using plantri: `./plantri -p -m2 -c2 -e15:15 -f6 12 ` But it takes 442.97 sec. So if the number of vertices increases, it may take more times.